# Как сделать ошибку для json-ответа со статусом и сообщением?

Tags: java, json, spring, исключения, сообщение

Я хочу прокидывать сообщение об ошибке, таким образом чтобы были поля

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-07-26T13:30:53.428+00:00",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "path": "/throws"
    "message": "Ошибка возникла по причине №100500"
}
```

К примеру, **org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException** прокидывая вот так:

`throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Ошибка возникла по причине")`;

Приводит к такому json'у:

```
  {
        "timestamp": "2023-07-26T13:30:53.428+00:00",
        "status": 400,
        "error": "Bad Request",
        "path": "/throws"
    }
```

То есть сообщение об ошибке не передается, хотя выходной **json** почти устраивает - передает код ошибки, название ошибки, часть url запроса.
Пробовал от него унаследоваться и добавить поле - ничего не вышло.

**Вопрос:** есть ли в спринге какой-нибудь класс ошибки, схожий по функционалу с `ResponseStatusException`, такой чтобы в него засунуть причину(сообщение об ошибке), статус, код ошибки, время и часть url?. Если нет, как сделать класс ошибки с такими полями, чтобы из любого места контроллера кинуть и получить в постмане подобное сообщение.

Comment: Ну, например, у вас есть какой-нибудь `@ExceptionHandler`. Можно сделать так, чтобы его метод возвращал `ResponseEntity<YourException>`, где `YourException` - это собственный класс-сущность исключения с нужными полями. Создаёте объект от неё, заполняете поля чем надо, пусть созданный объект называется `ex`. И затем возвращаете из метода `new ResponseEntity(ex, HttpStatus.STATUS_OF_ERROR)`.

Comment: @Byb не очень решение подходит. К примеру, есть контроллер который возвращает некоторую сущность. К примеру `@GetMapping("/getDoc")
    public ResponseEntity<Document> getDocument`. Тут не вернуть просто  `ResponseEntity<YourException>` из-за несоответствия типов

Comment: Так а можно же для этого написать другой метод. Ну то есть, вот есть обычный метод-контроллер, замапленный на какой-то URL и возвращающий что-то. В нём бросается исключение. Мы знаем конкретный тип этого исключения, поэтому можем написать метод-контроллер, помеченный как `@ExceptionHandler`. Этот метод принимает в качестве параметра исключение (конкретный метод вроде по эксепшнам как раз и распознаётся), а возвращать может что угодно. В том числе и то, что я написал в первом комментарии.

Comment: https://github.com/zalando/problem - вам сюда